# Angular reactive form not able to pass data to child component

Tags: angular, types, angular-reactive-forms

im working with angular reactive form but having some issues while passing the `formGroup` data from parent to child component.
here is the error that im getting

> ```
>   [96msrc/app/invoice-form/invoice-form.component.html[0m:[93m3[0m:[93m103[0m
> ```
>
> - [91merror[0m[90m TS2740: [0mType 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormGroup': controls,
>   registerControl, addControl, removeControl, and 3 more.
>
> [7m3[0m     <app-form-item *ngFor = "let formItem of
> getInvoiceItem.controls; let i = index" [indexId] = "i"
> [invoiceFormItem] = "formItem" > [7m [0m [91m
>
> ```
>  
> [96msrc/app/invoice-form/invoice-form.component.ts[0m:[93m9[0m:[93m16[0m
>     [7m9[0m   templateUrl: './invoice-form.component.html',
>     [7m [0m [96m               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
>     Error occurs in the template of component InvoiceFormComponent.
> ```

**Parent Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormArray, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
    import { FormItemComponent } from './form-item/form-item.component';
    
    

@Component({
  selector: 'app-invoice-form',
  templateUrl: './invoice-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./invoice-form.component.css']
})
export class InvoiceFormComponent implements OnInit {

  public invoiceFormItems: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    item:new FormControl(''),
    quantity:new FormControl(''),
    price:new FormControl(''),
    total:new FormControl(''),
  });
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createInvoiceItemForm();
  }

  public createInvoiceItemForm(): void 
  {
    this.invoiceFormItems = new FormGroup({
      items : new FormArray([
        FormItemComponent.addInvoiceItem(),
        FormItemComponent.addInvoiceItem(),
      ])
    });
  }
  get getInvoiceItem():FormArray {
    return this.invoiceFormItems?.get('items') as FormArray;
  }
  public submitInvoiceForm()
  {
  
  }

  public addNewInvoiceItems()
  {
    this.getInvoiceItem.push(FormItemComponent.addInvoiceItem());
  }
}
```

**Parent Component html template**

```
<form class="form " class="mt-2" autocomplete="off" [formGroup]="invoiceFormItems" (ngSubmit)="submitInvoiceForm()">

    <app-form-item *ngFor = "let formItem of getInvoiceItem.controls; let i = index" [indexId] = "i" [invoiceFormItem] = "formItem" >
      
    </app-form-item>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col p-0">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" (click)="addNewInvoiceItems()" [disabled]="!invoiceFormItems.valid"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i>
                Add
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Child Component**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-item',
  templateUrl: './form-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-item.component.css']
})
export class FormItemComponent {

  @Input() public invoiceFormItem: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    item: new FormControl(''),
    quantity: new FormControl(''),
    price: new FormControl(''),
    total: new FormControl('')
  });

  constructor() { }
  static addInvoiceItem(): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      item: new FormControl(''),
      quantity: new FormControl(''),
      price: new FormControl(''),
      total: new FormControl('')
    });
  }
}
```

**Child html template**

```
<div [formGroup] = "invoiceFormItem"  >
<div class="mt-4">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group">
      <label for="item-name">Item</label>
      <input type="txt" class="form-control" id="item-name" name="item" formControlName="item" placeholder="Enter Item">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group">
      <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity"  name ="quantity" formControlName="quantity" placeholder="Enter Quantity">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group">
      <label for="price">Price</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price"  name ="price" formControlName="price" placeholder="Item Price">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group">
      <label for="total">Total</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="total" name ="total" formControlName="total" placeholder="Item Total Amount">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group d-flex align-items-center pt-4">
      <button class="btn btn-danger"  type="button"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>  
</div>
```

The problem is I cant bind custom property to pass down the data(FormGroup) here

```
 <app-form-item *ngFor = "let formItem of getInvoiceItem.controls; let i = index" [invoiceFormItem] = "formItem" >
      
    </app-form-item>
```

Why is that error is occurring while binding the custom property for the child component, am i doing anything wrong?
Any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This is not how you should design your reactive forms. why you are passing form group from parent if you are calling child component method in it?

Comment: @Vimal Patel Passing is doing for get the data from each formgroup in the child components and establish the connections. Was that wrong ?

Comment: why are you doing that, why not defined the form in child component.

Answer (score 1):

Angular (really typescript) has no idea about your "formItem", the only is create a function like

```
getGroup(index){
  return (this.invoiceFormItems.get('items') as FormArray)
               .at(index) as FormGroup
}
```

An pass like

```
<app-form-item *ngFor = "let formItem of getInvoiceItem.controls; 
       let i = index" [indexId] = "i" [invoiceFormItem] = "getGroup(i)">
```